# JAXB context to rename the namespace and add a xml header

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Using JAXBContext, I have a package to create a XML header but the namespace is not generating properly.I need to change the XML from the first one to the second one.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                        .newInstance("com.oracle.xmlns.eos.v2"); 
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
```

From :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns1:DPC
        xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/V2"
        xmlns:ns1="http://url/xsd/DPC"
        xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing"
        xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/IC/V1"/>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <ns1:DPC
            xmlns:ns1="http://url/xsd/DPC"
            xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/addressing"
            xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/IC/V1"
            xmlns:coreEB="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/EB/V1"
            xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/V2"/>
```

Please suggest Is it possible to change the first to second.This needs to add  `xmlns:coreEB="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/EB/V1"` and rename the namespace from `xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/V2"` to  `xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/V2"`.

Answer (score 0):

Both your variations are the same except that second has one more namespace `http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/EB/V1`

JAXB marshaller marshals namespaces from all known to its context classes or packages.
Your examples means that from your package `com.oracle.xmlns.eos.v2` there is no references to the package containing classes with JAXB annotations for `http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/EB/V1` namespace

So,

first - double check your JAXB classes/packages structure, problem can be there.

second - if you did not find discrepancy or not sure about that... try to add needed package for `http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects
/EB/V1` namespace explicitly to JAXBContext separated by `:` like

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance("com.oracle.xmlns.eos.v2:com.oracle.xmlns.enterpriseobjects.eb.v1");
```

You will have needed namespace in generated XML. 
Perhaps you will not have any elements or attributes for that namespace, because JAXB did not find it is needed, but namespace will be there.

Just keep in mind a package must be a JAXB, either with jaxb `ObjectFactory` class or `jaxb.index` file.

Comment: The problem is the namespace is generating properly if it is as a jar but in war and deployed in WLS it is not generating properly. So I need to replace the namespace. There is class used and using marhal method it is mapped but here please suggest is there any way to replace the namespace.

Comment: Namespaces generate properly according to JAXB context and JAXB object structure. JAXB marshaller puts all namespaces known by context into XML. If namspace not identified by context it will not be there. That is a point.